# How do I convert a .cer certificate to .pem?

Tags: ssl-certificate, convert

I have a `.cer` certificate and I would like to convert it to the `.pem` format.

If I remember correctly, I used to be able to convert them by exporting the `.cer` in Base64, then renaming the file to `.pem` .

How do I convert a `.cer` certificate to `.pem`?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Convert a DER file (.crt .cer .der) to PEM

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

[Source](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The CER file is exported from the Windows certificate export tool. It has the following form: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...D2H
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. From openssl, I get the following error: `error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1338:
error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:390:Type=X509`

Comment: Then your certificate is already in PEM format. Just rename it from `certificate.cer` to `certificate.pem`.

Comment: Earlier asked here – [How to convert .crt to .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4691699/95735)

Answer (score 24):

To convert a .cer file to .pem, open a terminal and run the following command:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -outform pem -out certificate.pem
```

Replace "certificate.cer" with the name of the source certificate file you want to convert, and "certificate.pem" with the name you want for the converted certificate.

Answer (score 17):

When openssl is not available on your system you could alternatively convert certificates with the java **keytool**.

However you have to create a java keystore (JKS) first. The certificates can then be imported and exported in different formats.

```
keytool -genkey -alias test -keystore <key store file>
keytool -delete -alias test -keystore <key store file>
```

Converting from DER to PEM:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test -file <der certificate file> -keystore test.keystore 
keytool -exportcert -alias test -file <pem certificate file> -rfc -keystore test.keystore
```

[This blog post explains how to convert certificate formats in detail](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/09/convert-certificates-pem-der.html)

Comment: I did this and the .pem file is almost identical to the .cer file, just wrapped differently.

Comment: @endolith in that case they are both .pem files. A .cer file can be .der or .pem encoded, this question assumes .der encoding, which you did not have.

Answer (score 16):

#### Answer

- If your certificate is exported with `DER encoding`, then use the accepted answer:

  ```
  openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
  ```
- If your certificate is exported with `Base-64 encoding`, then rename the file's extension from `.cer` to `.pem` since the file is already in `.pem` format.

#### How to tell that your `.cer` file is in `.pem` format?

See [this stack-o answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215851/564406), quoted here:

> A `.pem` format certificate file will most likely be ASCII-readable.
> It will have a line that starts with: 
>  `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` 
> ...followed by `Base-64 encoded` data, followed by a 
> `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` 
>  at the end. There may be other lines before or after.

For example, a `.pem` certificate (shortened):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG6DCCBNCgAwIBAgITMgAAGCeh8HZoCVDcnwAAAAAYJzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
ADBAMRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNkb3Ix
EjAQBgNVBAMTCURPUi1TVUJDQTAeFw0yMDA1MDExNTI0MTJaFw0yMjA1MDExNTI0
MTJaMBYxFDASBgNVBAMTC3dwZG9yd2VibDE2MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 5):

We mustn't forget that Windows can do this natively:

```
certutil.exe -encode <der file> <pem file>
```

and in the other direction:

```
certutil.exe -decode <pem file> <der file>
```

It works with certificates and PKCS#10 requests.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the file extension worked for me:

`mv filename.cer filename.pem`

Comment: That only works if the content of the file is already PEM encoded. Changing the file extension does not change the content of the file. In many cases, a program would also not care if the file extension is `der` or `pem`, and rather check the content.