# How to convert .cer and .key file to .pem?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

I have a .cer certificate, .key file and I would like to convert it to the .pem format.

How do I convert them to .pem?

Comment: That really depends on the types of the files you have. Both .cer and .key may be in PEM format already. Just open the files in your text editor of choice. If it is text with stuff like "--- BEGIN CERTIFCATE ---", then it is already PEM format. If it isn't, you'll need to find out what format you have. You can use the "file" utility, that should tell you what kind of file you're dealing with.

Comment: Also, see https://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-do-i-convert-a-cer-certificate-to-pem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a .cer certificate to .pem?](https://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-do-i-convert-a-cer-certificate-to-pem)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the .key PK,
and .cer/.crt/.cert file in the correct format
(i think common-name is mandatory)

**// in Linux**

```
cat x.key x.cert > x.pem
```

**// in Windows**

```
copy /b x.key+x.cert x.pem
```

Comment: This is valid if the files are already in a PEM format and just having a different name suffix (refer to the comment to the question).

Answer (score 1):

I used openssl to do the conversion and it works.

Convert 'certificate.cer' to 'certificate.pem'

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Convert 'yourkeyfile.key' to 'yourkey.pem'

```
openssl rsa -in yourkeyfile.key -out yourkeyfile.pem
```

Bundle both certificate.pem and yourkey.pem as a single cert+key.pem

```
cat certificate.pem yourkey.pem > cert+key.pem
```

Comment: welcome, I would suggest that you edit your question and add more information and some references to verify your solution.